# Changing order or row and column labels in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
      c3ann c3nfx   c3per   c4ann   c4per   pastr   primf
c3ann   1    0      1       0       1       0       1
c3nfx   1    0      1       0       1       0       1
c3per   1    0      1       0       1       0       1
c4ann   1    0      1       0       1       0       1
c4per   1    0      1       0       1       0       1
pastr   1    0      1       0       1       0       1
primf   1    0      1       0       1       0       1
```

I would like to reorder the rows and columns so that the order is this:

```
primf pastr c3ann   c3nfx   c3per   c4ann   c4per
```

I can do this for just the columns like this:

```
cols = ['primf', 'pastr', 'c3ann',  'c3nfx',    'c3per',    'c4ann',    'c4per']
df = df[cols]
```

How do I do this such that the row headers are also changed appropriately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to reorder both the columns and index at the same time.

```
df = df.reindex(index=cols, columns=cols)
```